# Há alguma alternativa para PRIORITY_MAX que esta obsoleto?

Tags: android, android-notification

Estou usando a classe `NotificationCompat.Builder` para criar uma notificação no qual ela tem que ficar no topo com a prioridade máxima.

Eu defino a prioridade da notificação da seguinte forma:

```
notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

No entanto, o Android Studio diz que o campo `PRIORITY_MAX` esta *deprecated*.

## Pergunta

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber se há alguma alternativa para `PRIORITY_MAX` e que não esteja deprecated ou obsoleto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [`setPriority`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) ficou obsoleto a partir da *API 26* e na documentação recomenda-se utilizar método [`setImportance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setImportance(int))

Você pode usar [`IMPORTANCE_HIGH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_HIGH) no lugar de `PRIORITY_MAX`.

Abaixo os valores que pode ser informado como parâmetro, esses valores estão disponíveis a partir da *API 24*.

- [`IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED)
- [`IMPORTANCE_NONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_NONE)
- [`IMPORTANCE_MIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_MIN)
- [`IMPORTANCE_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_LOW)
- [`IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
- [`IMPORTANCE_HIGH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_HIGH)